# Register all dll in a directory in GAC Silently in powershell

Tags: powershell, gac

I have to register all .dll files in a directory to GAC silently without any screen popup.
How can i do this using powershell.
Please help :)

Answer (score 6):

I am the author of [PowerShell GAC](https://powershellgac.codeplex.com/). With PowerShell GAC you don't need gacutil and you can install all dlls in a folder to the GAC with the following command.

```
# Can only be run from an elevated prompt
Add-GacAssembly C:\Folder\*.dll
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [gacutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79.aspx).

```
& gacutil.exe -i <strongly named DLL>
```

Note - the DLL must meet the requirements of being installable into the GAC.

Comment: what is strongly named dll.I am able to install it when clicking on install button from gacutil window,but using above command

Comment: FYI the `&` is unnecessary. `gacutil.exe` will be parsed as a command and not a string.

Comment: @user1595214 `<strongly named dll>` is just a placeholder for the path of the assembly you want to put in the GAC.

Comment: @KeithHill only not necessary if running it from its current directory. Most instances I see have spaces in its path e.g. `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\gacutil.exe` so to call it say the root of C you'd need `& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\gacutil.exe"`. I just usually also just use it because it works in all scenarios.

Comment: I guess I usually have my PowerShell configured with the SDK bin dir in my path. So I just exeucte `gacutil -i ...`.  PSCX has a very handy Import-VisualStudioVars function that will configure your PowerShell environment for various flavors of Visual Studio.

Comment: @KeithHill : hi keith,just to confirm a few things as i dont have much idea about Gacutil,Actually i am able to register dll in Gacutil if i am launching gacutil.exe and dragging dropping dll over the interface,so does it mean that all those dlls are strongly signed.And if they are strongly signed,why not i am able to do the same through command line.

Comment: Maybe you have not run powershell specifically as an administrator?

Answer (score 3):

The .Net Framework already contains methods to register components in the GAC. No need to add SDKs and third party plugins.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")
$publisher = New-Object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish

# For installation 
$publisher.GacInstall("C:\Components\MyComponent.dll")

# For removal
$publisher.GacRemove("C:\Components\MyComponent.dll")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a late answer but maybe someone will find it useful. Assuming the path to gacutil.exe is known the following script might be used:

```
Get-ChildItem "<full_path_to_your_directory>\*" -include "*.dll" | ForEach-Object -Process { gacutil -i $_.FullName }
```

<full_path_to_your_directory> shall be replaced with the path to the directory in subject. Trailing "\*" is required.